# Variable Scope: cross-class function call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `vehicle` and a `product` object and I need vehicle to call a function within product.... I can't seem to figure it out, what should I do here?

```
var vehicle = function () {
    return {
        init: function () {
            var that = this;

            jQuery('.vehicle-year-profile .options .delete').bind('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                that.remove(jQuery(e.currentTarget).parents('.vehicle-year-profile'));
            });

            jQuery('.vehicle-year-profile .options .edit').bind('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                that.edit(jQuery(e.currentTarget).parents('.vehicle-year-profile').attr('id'));
            });

            jQuery('#association-detail .save').bind('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                that.save();
            });
        },
        edit: function (id) {},
        save: function () {},
        remove: function (el) {},
        reset: function () {}
    }
}();

var product = function () {
    return {
        refreshHistory: function () {}
    };
}();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
product.refreshHistory();
```

?? The variable "product" is global (or at least *relatively* global), so code inside the "vehicle" object can refer to it directly.

Comment: Thanks @Marcel! I'm old and I can't see anything :-)